# Pre or post check when deleting records from a table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

For a web application where deleting records happens often, what is the best, if we take performance into consideration?

- check if the record has any reletaionship with other tables and prevent the user from deleting.

  ex : the query will be like this

  ```
   if not exist(select * from table1 where tableX_id = @id) and 
         not exist(select * from table2 where tableX_id = @id)
         ...
      then 
         delete from tableX where id = @id
  ```

  or
- perform the `delete` and let the RDBMS rais an error due to the `foriegn key` constraint

  ```
    try{
         Service.DeleteRecord(id)
    }catch{
         Handle the error here
    }
  ```

  in this case the query will be simple

  ```
   delete from TableX where id = @id
  ```

Comment: Why can't you use cascade delete on the related tables?

Comment: @Arion I don't want to delete records referenced in other tables

Comment: Why do you not want that? I mean you do not have to check anything when deleting. You do not have to catch any errors. You can just leave sql-server do it "job"

Comment: @anouar204: A CASCADE is assigned to a single FK reference, it won't delete *everything* by default, only on the table to which the FK originates.

Comment: I'd say that all that logic should be in whatever stored procedure you are calling to do the delete. Get that to just return the number of rows deleted and check that in the code. If you are just writing direct deletes and not using stored procedures then convert code to stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the goal is to prevent rows from being deleted only in the case where actually running the delete would yield an error because it is referenced by other tables, then I suggest you check for the violation before letting SQL Server check for you. [I've done some testing on this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and letting SQL catch the error or just using TRY/CATCH can be more expensive if you expect even a moderate amount of failures. With the proper indexes in place, the additional cost of performing the check is negligible; however the cost of NOT doing the check is certainly LESS negligible.

Comment: Check then Delete requires a suitable transaction (and suitable isolation and locking) to prevent races - otherwise, you have to deal with the possibilities of errors coming from the Delete anyway.

Comment: That "with the proper indexes in place" in your answer makes all the difference and may very well be counter-productive in other scenarios or simply not possible to do for other business reasons.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, I'm not saying it's a substitute, you will probably still want try/catch or other error handling in place, but if at the time of the check if the row fails validation there is no point in entering the delete phase just in case some other transaction has made it possible that the delete will succeed. Still using the try/catch (or just performing the delete when the validation check succeeds) will still catch the edge case where in between the check and the delete the delete became invalid.

Comment: Did you think that if we do a check in many tables the cost of those chekes will still be negligible?

Comment: @anouar204 Not sure if we can agree on what "negligible" means, or how optimized the checks you write will be, but if SQL Server has to do those checks anyway when it tries the delete, what are you saving? The nice thing about the checks is that you can customize them such that you check the least expensive tables first (which you can't control for violations), add indexes to support your checks (which the violations may not use), etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would use database triggers (or ON CASCADE DELETE) to handle any relationships -- the tools available will depend on your RDBMS.

Comment: I don't want to delete records referenced in other tables

Comment: Since you specifically asked about checking relationships with other tables, how do you plan to handle orphaned related records?

Comment: I think that's the point - if he deletes a row in X where no row in Y points to it, it's not going to leave any orphans.

Comment: I asked for a check in order to delete or not to delete the record not to do a clean up

Comment: Okay, I understand your situation better now that you've edited the original post.  Since this is a straight forward question of deleting the records or not, I would perform the logic in the stored procedure and return a boolean value, error message or other indicator to the application.

Comment: Have you done any performance test before, to know how better is your approach over the `try catch` one?

Comment: Yes, but my performance tests will not necessarily address your specific situation.  I suggest you run a trace file both ways over some time and compare the two options.  It looks like you plan to do the IF statement in code -- this requires extra calls to the DB and may really hurt your performance.  You could also, if you choose, do the IF statements in your SP, which is what I think both Aaron and I are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, performing the delete and letting the RDBMS take care of business. By implementing the check yourself, you are incurring into an extra operation that the RDBMS will perform anyway.